# What's the best practice for sequential dialogs in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I have an application that has to calculate some numbers based on some input data. This data can either come from a file or can be entered manually (it's only 5-6 values). I want to present a dialog box that basically asks "Do you want to load data from file or enter it manually?". If "load" is selected, I want to present a file open dialog box, and then parse the selected file to extract the relevant data. If "manual" is selected I want to present a custom CDialog subclass where the user can enter the the same data that would have been extracted from a data file.

My primary question is what is considered the best practice for stringing this together?

Should I call the dialog boxes sequentially like this?

```
// pseudocode
void foo(){
    status = MessageBox("Do you want to enter data from file?");

    if (status == YES) {
        filename = CFileDialog();
        inputdata = processInputFile(filename);
    }
    else {
        CManualEntryDialog.doModal();
        inputdata = CManualEntryDialog.data;
    }

    // calculate output data from input data...
}
```

Or should I subclass CDialog and call CFileDialog & CManualEntryDialog from within that sublasses event handlers?

Comment: What's wrong with one dialog and paneling/tabbing the two types of input? (or load in a usercontrol in the same dialog if you want to really compartmentalize it) [just curious]

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, except I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is MFC, not .NET.

Comment: Those aren't actually sequential, unless you're counting the MessageBox. Otherwise, that looks reasonable. Personally, I'd have two different menu options (Data / Import... and Data / Manual Entry...), but that's a UI thing. Alternatively, present the manual entry dialog, and put an Import... button on it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with opening a Yes/No dialog (the messagebox), and opening another dialog based on the result. You really don't have to go through all the trouble of subclassing a dialog. But from UI perspective, I would rather show just one dialog than two. One option is to use two different menu options, like Roger mentioned, but if you don't have a menu, you can also show the manual data entry dialog by default, and have there a button to import data from file. This way, at least one use case would require just one dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that at least a significant fraction of your users will understand the numbers involved; they're not "magical". Therefore, it would make sense to show them after loading. You can nicely integrate this with the manual entry option.

Design one dialog with the 6 entry fields. Add a "Load" button that fills in these fields, but do not continue from there. This allows the user to verify and possibly modify these values. (Useful when he needs 4 out of the 5 values in the input file).

Do use a group box control around the 6 entry fields, with the Load/Ok/Cancel buttons outside. This makes it clear that the three buttons apply to the whole group.

The UX advantage of this approach is that it's more open to exploration. You don't force the user to choose up fron how to interact with your application. And with this level of complexity, it's unlikely to overwhelm your target audience.

Comment: That's the solution I ended up going with based on a comment from Boaz Yaniv above. I added an "Import..." button that pops up a CFileDialog, then feeds to the filename to a parser object, then updates the original dialog's fields with the data from the file. User still has to hit OK to accept the data.

Answer (score 0):

For sequential dialogs, I would recommand a wizard process using the CPropertyPage and CPropertySheet classes.

Here is an example :
http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/bulentozkir/pp_wizard04212005064904AM/pp_wizard.aspx

http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=79